# fetch() sends the wrong URL Request to server

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have encountered a strange problem, doing a POST request using fetch(). It should have been easy, but I keep having an error code 405 from the server. Furthermore, the request URL should be only "http://localhost:3000/api/teddies/order", but somehow the local Visual_liveserver keeps adding in front of the URL request (the local server is hosted on this with port 5500 : http://127.0.0.1:5500)... In the image below you can see the error code 405 and this strange request URL.

[Network inspector of the POST method : fetch()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twuXh.png)

By following this link, you will be able to access [the Git of this projet](https://github.com/Kaerbran/MatthiasAznarSchwarz_5bis_13032021.git). Don't hesitate to have a look at it ;) The file that calls these functions is called "pageFillingPanier.js".

But in short find below the code of the function that has the fetch in it:

```
const sendPurchaseRequest = async function (dataToSend) {
console.log(dataToSend);
try {
    let response = await fetch('h​ttp://localhost:3000/api/teddies/order', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(dataToSend) 
    });

    console.log(response.ok); //it shows false...
    
    let responseData = await response.json();
    sessionStorage.setItem('memoryResponse', responseData.orderId);
    //window.location = 'remerciement.html';

} catch (error){
    console.log(error);
}
```

}

Find below the code that calls the function:

```
document.getElementById('bttFormSend').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
let formPurchaseOrder = {
    contact : {
        firstName : document.getElementById('firstName').value,
        lastName : document.getElementById('lastName').value,
        email : document.getElementById('email').value,
        address : document.getElementById('adress').value,
        city : document.getElementById('city').value},
    products : []
};
for (let index = 0; index < basketToDisplay.length; index++) {
    formPurchaseOrder.products.push(basketToDisplay[index].id);
}

//this function send the POST request to the server
sendPurchaseRequest (formPurchaseOrder);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the image suggests, there's a non visible unicode character present in the url. This happens sometimes when you copy and paste the url from some other places.

`%E2%80%8B` in url encoded form and `​` without encoded.

Remove it and browser will recognize it as a valid url.

```js
console.log(encodeURIComponent('h​ttp://localhost:3000/api/teddies/order'))
```

[image]

The url `http://127.0.0.1:5500/` is added because browser doesn't detect the supplied url as a valid url hence consider it as a path and prepend your current url to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sagar, you just made a man very happy and annoyed... Because this is truly a shitty mistake. Pardon my French... As a frenchman I'm pardoned ;)