# fetch() sends a request to a wrong endpoint

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

I think my question is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67323979/fetch-sends-the-wrong-url-request-to-server) in so far that the `fetch()` API is sending requests to wrong end points on my backend with the response being a 405 error. However, my problem manifests differently and I've spent the better part of a day figuring out what's going wrong and where.

So I'm a Docker multi-container setup to proxy requests through nginx from a React frontend to a Django REST Framework backend. I'm able to visit and link through unprotected routes on my frontend and can directly access endpoints on my backend by keying in the URL directly in my browser. So I know there's nothing wrong with the server and proxy setup.

But when I try to interact with elements in my frontend that request data from the backend I'm running up against a wall. For example, my frontend has to call `/api/auth/login` to get the credentials to login. I've set up a location called `/api/` in my nginx config file [Config file contents are at the end]. In my React component where I've used the `fetch` function, I've used `/api/auth/login`. But the request never goes to `/api/auth/login`. Instead, it *always* goes to `/auth/login`, which doesn't exist, kicking up a 405 response.

I have no idea why it's dropping the leading `/api/` part. I've gone over multiple resources for setting up this nginx config file and still can't figure this out. I would appreciate it greatly if someone could shine a light on why this is happening.

React component code calling the `fetch` function:

```
const formHandler = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = {
       // username / password
    };

    const response = await fetch('/api/auth/login/', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    })
    // doing things with the returned response data
};
```

My nginx config file:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    location / {
        root /var/www/frontend;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
       try_files $uri @proxy_api;
    }

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        root /api/;
    }

    location @proxy_api {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://backend:8000;
    }
}
```

`backend` in the config file is the name of the service in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

There was a point where I'd initially made a mistake and had called `/auth/login` instead of `/api/auth/login` in my React component. Even after I corrected the mistake, because the bug persisted, I figured there was some cache sitting somewhere and completely deleted the docker images and re-ran `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` multiple times to no avail.

**UPDATE - SOLVED**

I found the problem and the issue wasn't cache or anything like that. I used to store my frontend build in a Docker volume and then move it over to my nginx container once it was built. The issue was that the data in this container wasn't being updated with every build. I guess Docker doesn't rewrite folders on every `docker-compose build`. So I just deleted the volume every time I changed my frontend and I was good to go.

Comment: Have you cleared your browser's cache?

Comment: @RichardSmith Yup, cleared all cache. Both browser and docker. At this point, I'm going to see if I can build the docker containers on another machine and see if it works properly. A rare case of 'It's NOT working on my machine'.